# MongoDB C# Driver - Update without Set/Replace

Tags: c#, mongodb, updating

I am communicating with a MongoDB database that is shared by another application that uses some fields that my application doesn't use or care about.

Throughout my code, I use `Update.Replace` to update the object. The problem is that it replaces the entire document in the database with the one from my POCO object, causing the properties used by the other application to be removed.

I could do `Update.Set`, but I would have to use that ALOT of times. `Update.Replace` is very convenient because it auto converts (by reflection) the POCO object to a `BsonDocument`.

How do I auto-generate an `Update.Set` so that I don't have to call it for every member?

Comment: Remember that Mongo is stored in `JSON`, so it's `dynamic` by default. My recommendation would be to recover what's already there, leverage the `dynamic` type, add your properties, and then save back. This will ensure that it retains the object that's already there.

Comment: I know. The problem is that I use POCOs throughout my entire library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have to make an extra network call to get the whole document, then do a replace.

I take the existing document and do...

```
_caseCollection.Update(Query<Case>.EQ(x => x.Id, caseItem.Id), Update.Replace(existingDocument.Merge(caseItem.ToBsonDocument(), true)));
```

This will retain any fields that the other application is using.